Error al utilizar la funcion de php header("Location: index.php?" . http_build_query($query_params));
tengo problemas con este codigo. Lo mas importante es que en el entorno de prueba (xampp) funciona correcto pero en produccion queda la pantalla en blanco sin que se cargue en url la llamadas. Ej ADMIN/index.php?operacion=venta. Les comparto el codigo: Desde ya muchas gracias
    // Verificar si se ha enviado el formulario
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  // Capturar los valores de los filtros
  $operacion = isset($_POST['operacion']) ? $_POST['operacion'] : '';
  $tipo = isset($_POST['tipo']) ? $_POST['tipo'] : '';
  $localidad = isset($_POST['localidad']) ? $_POST['localidad'] : '';
  $palabraClave = isset($_POST['palabraClave']) ? $_POST['palabraClave'] : '';

  // Construir la URL con los parámetros de búsqueda
  $query_params = [];

  if (!empty($operacion))
    $query_params['operacion'] = $operacion;


  // Redirigir a la misma página con los parámetros en la URL
  header("Location: index.php?" . http_build_query($query_params));
  exit;
}

// Capturar los valores de los filtros desde la URL
$operacion = isset($_GET['operacion']) ? $_GET['operacion'] : '';
$tipo = isset($_GET['tipo']) ? $_GET['tipo'] : '';
$localidad = isset($_GET['localidad']) ? $_GET['localidad'] : '';
$palabraClave = isset($_GET['palabraClave']) ? $_GET['palabraClave'] : '';

// Construir la consulta SQL con filtros
$sql = "SELECT * FROM propiedades WHERE 1=1";


if (!empty($operacion)) {
  $sql .= " AND operacion = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $operacion) . "'";
}

if (!empty($tipo)) {
  $sql .= " AND tipo = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $tipo) . "'";
}
if (!empty($localidad)) {
  $sql .= " AND localidad = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $localidad) . "'";
}


$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);


Hola. Sería bueno que revises el log de errores en el entorno donde el código no funciona. Si por algún motivo no sabes dónde revisarlo, pon estas tres líneas al inicio de tu archivo .php y dale a guardar y prueba de nuevo. ini_set('display_errors', '1');  ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');  error_reporting(E_ALL); Esto es un método de depuración rápida, no lo propagues, más bien aprende a activar / revisar el log de errores de una forma global.

No se porqué Cedano no agregó una respuesta, pero siendo manejo de errores podemos buscar el log de errores primero.
Vale aclarar que debemos revisar el entorno de desarrollo (local), y el de producción, ya que si no están dando el mismo resultado, es por que hay diferencias, y lo ideal es que no las hayan.
Generalmente, la ubicación del log de errores en XAMPP es:
xampp/php/logs/php_error_log

Tienes que aprender donde se ubican los diferentes log de errores, de todo lo que desarrollas, por que es un constante manejo de errores lo que hay que hacer.
Una vez revisado el log, debes identificar los errores, y el error en este caso que corta la ejecución, si la pantalla se queda en blanco, y es capturado ahí, debería aparecer.

Ahora, lo siguiente es para ser usado solo durante el desarrollo, en el entorno local, esto se debe quitar una vez pasa a producción.
Al inicio de tu código, añades:
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // Mostrar errores (1-mostrar, 0-noMostrar)
ini_set('log_errors', 1);     // Habilitar el registro de errores

Y modificamos tu código, en la sección donde falla, para mostrar TODO error que podamos encontrar.
//Usaremos el try-catch, para obtener todo posible error
try {
    // Verificar si se ha enviado el formulario con POST
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // Capturamos los valores de la llamada
        $operacion = isset($_POST['operacion']) ? $_POST['operacion'] : '';
        $tipo = isset($_POST['tipo']) ? $_POST['tipo'] : '';
        $localidad = isset($_POST['localidad']) ? $_POST['localidad'] : '';
        $palabraClave = isset($_POST['palabraClave']) ? $_POST['palabraClave'] : '';

        // Construimos query_params
        $query_params = [];
        //Agregamos TODAS las variables (si falla alguna lo sabremos)
        if (!empty($operacion)) {
            $query_params['operacion'] = $operacion;
        }
        if (!empty($tipo)) {
            $query_params['tipo'] = $tipo;
        }
        if (!empty($localidad)) {
            $query_params['localidad'] = $localidad;
        }
        if (!empty($palabraClave)) {
            $query_params['palabraClave'] = $palabraClave;
        }

        // Verificamos si la construccion de le URL es correcta, de no serlo, mostramos los params
        $query_string = http_build_query($query_params);
        if ($query_string === false) {
            throw new Exception("Error al construir query_params: " . print_r($query_params, true));
        }

        // Intentamos redirigir, si es que falla, mostramos el error
        if (!header("Location: index.php?" . $query_string)) {
            throw new Exception("Error en la redirección a index.php: " . $query_string);
        }

        exit; //Detenemos el código acá, esto siempre va luego de intentar redirigir
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Si algun error aparece, lo registramos en el log (el anteriormente mencionado)
    error_log("Error en el formulario index.php: " . $e->getMessage());
    // Si algún error aparece, también confirmamos una salida por pantalla (para que no nos quede en blanco)
    echo "Ha ocurrido un error! Recuerda revisar el log";
}

Todas estas modificaciones, deberían ayudarte a encontrar cuál es exactamente el problema que tienes.
Una vez tengas el error, actualiza y compartelo, a saber cual es el error. (lo más probable es que sea un error de headers a todo esto, durante la redirección)
